# "That event does not belong to that event store" when trying to create a new calendar event

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar

I'm trying to save a new event on iPhone calendar, but it just keeps giving me this error:

> **Cannot Save Event — That event does not belong to that event store**

What can I do to fix this?

[image]

I'm using Google Calendar by default, but I get the same error even if I try to use another calendar, so I presume the fault is not in Google's servers. Never encountered this problem before – just started seeing it today. (Using iPhone 4 and iOS 5.0.1.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try these:

- Close the Calendar app [completely](http://isource.com/2010/06/28/how-to-close-an-app-in-ios-4-via-the-new-multitasking-bar/), then retry (**this worked for me**)
- Reboot iPhone
- Try editing the default calendar setting (Settings ->
  Mail, Contacts, Calendars -> Calendars)

If none of those helps, you could read through [this apple.com thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3375599?start=0&tstart=0) for more tips.

Comment: I followed all these instructions and my issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is jailbroken (and your calendar is backed up) this can be fixed fairly easily.

1. Turn off all calendars
2. Delete the contents of "/var/mobile/Library/Calendar" (you can use something like i-FunBox or iPhoneBrowser - both free).
3. Reboot the phone
4. Turn the calendars back on again

Fixed the issue for me right away.

Comment: I'd say anyone should [try these steps first](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/34442/150) (whether the phone is jailbroken or not), because it's quick &  *certainly* won't break anything.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that the cursor (or maybe "highlighter" is better - hard to see!) was still on another event that I had just modified.  I tried to use the "+" to add a second event to that day's calendar.  When I input a second event with different times, then pressed "Done" I got the message "That event does not belong to that event store."  I think the meaning of the error message is now clear - the second event couldn't be superimposed on the first.  So in my case simply touching a different time slot on the calendar, then entering the new appointment, solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I went to settings, icloud, then unchecked calendars. It asked me if I wanted to delete or keep events from the cloud on my phone. I chose DELETE. I waited one minute. I rechecked the calendar to use the cloud. I looked and all the ghost "new event" items that couldn't previously be deleted or altered were finally gone! Thank God!

Answer (score -1):

1. make sure to disconnect your phone from computer
2. delete calcube
3. close all apps
4. reboot iphone
5. reinstall calcube but do not select "calendar" yet.  just select "US Holiday" for now.
6. go through the setup
7. open calcube, go to "Settings", select "calendar" now
8. try adding in event in calendar in calcube
9. you may need to reboot again

I did these about 100 times, then it finally work. hahaha.....